# Moving files from more than one folder to the parent directory using CMD

Tags: cmd, command-line

I have a folder `Target` contains multiple folders,

each folder contains one file with the same name of the folder

[image: target folder]

[image: one of siblings folders]

I want to move the files in folders `Part1`,`Part2`,`Part3`,`Part4` and `Part5`

to parent folder ("Target" in this case) using `cmd` then delete the folders.

The result should be like that :

[image: result]

In Linux i could've used `mv Part*\*.* ..`

I've tried `copy "Part*\*" ""` command,
but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use wildcards in the middle of a path, they are only permitted in the last element; however, you may use [`for /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to first resolve wildcards in higher directory hierarchy levels...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Windows Command Prompt, `copy "Part*\*" ""` cannot work, because [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) are only permitted in the last element of a path but not somewhere in the middle.

To work around this, use a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to resolve wildcards in `Part*`, then let [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) deal with the remaining ones:

```
for /D %I in ("Part*") do @copy "%~I\*" ".."
```

---

To move the files rather than to copy, simply replace `copy` by [`move`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html). If you want to remove empty sub-directories then, append [`rd`](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) using [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```
for /D %I in ("Part*") do @move "%~I\*" ".." && @rd "%~I"
```

---

To use the above code fragments in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), ensure to double all the `%`-signs.

Comment: The directory is not empty

Comment: for /D %I in ("Part*") do @move "%~I\*" "." & rd "%~I"

Answer (score 1):

Use a For loop. The key to getting directory names in this code is `"dir /a:d"` which only lists directories. I put that into the `%%a` variable. Use `%~dp0` to refer to the directory the batch file is in. If your bat is somewhere else, do a find and replace all for that to the directory path you need. Lastly use `RMDIR` to remove each folder with `/q /s` to make it silent and remove all files within the directory (part1 part2 etc...) and the directories themselves.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:d /b "%~dp0"') do (
        copy "%~dp0%%a\*.*" "%~dp0"
        RMDIR /q /s "%~dp0%%a"
        )
```